# git adds file from outside repo folder?

Tags: git

I am creating a repo for my dotfiles that distribute all over on my machine. I picked the directory with most of the dotfiles and created the git repo there. Now I need to add the dotfiles that are NOT in this git repo directory.

I thought I found a way and did

```
git --work-tree=/ add  /another/path/.vimrc
```

The file is successfully added and pushed as the first commit. However, later I changed the file. When I did `git commit -m 'edit .vimrc'`, I got

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
...
no changes added to commit
```

Why is this the case? Did I add the outside file wrongly?

Comment: why not just create a symlink to the files you want to include in your dot files repo.  That is what I did.  And you can view my dotfiles here,
https://github.com/ipatch/dotfiles

Comment: @Chris Just tried creating symlink with `ln -s`, but git is only saving the content of that link instead of the actual file. How did you do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What Chris meant is that you need to put your file in the repo under version control and the softlink is outside and pointing to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--work-tree=/` option changes the work-tree *temporarily*, for the duration of the single command, `git ... add /another/path/.vimrc`.

What gets added to your repository is the remainder of the name.  So your repository now has a file named `another/path/.vimrc`.

If you had run:

```
git --work-tree=/another/path add .vimrc
```

you would have added a file named `.vimrc` to your repository.

Later, another Git command such as:

```
git checkout <revision> -- another/path/.vimrc
```

or:

```
git checkout <revision> -- .vimrc
```

extracts the file (`another/path/.vimrc` or `.vimrc`) to the *current* work tree, from the specified revision.  That current work tree is whatever you have specified *this time* with `--work-tree=`, or by default, the implied work-tree based on `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.